# Selenium 3 with Firefox: active did not match a known command

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, scalatest, geckodriver

I am trying to write a test which involves the latest **Firefox (48.0.2)** using the lastest **geckodriver.exe (v0.10.0)** and the following dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <!-- version 3 is needed for current Firefox -->
        <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My test starts like this

```
class LoginSpec extends FeatureSpec with GivenWhenThen with Firefox 
{
    val website = "http://localhost:8080/"

    feature("Landing page")
    {    
        scenario("Wrong password")
        {
          Given("someone on the website")
          go to website

          When("he tries to login with a wrong password")
          login("mbee", "bad password")

          Then("he will stay on the login page")
          usernameField.isDisplayed
          passwordField.isDisplayed
        }
    }

    def login(username: String, password: String)
    {
      click on usernameField
      enter(username)
      click on passwordField
      enter(password)
      submit()
    }

    def usernameField = textField("j_username")

    def passwordField = pwdField("j_password")        
}
```

First I tried **with Chrome** which was fine. But **with Firefox** I already get an error for `enter(username)`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST /session/2769cbe9-f066-4a63-ad49-990eec1c6740/element/active did not match a known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
...
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.activeElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:968)
    at org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser$ActiveElementTarget.switch(WebBrowser.scala:1502)
    at org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser$ActiveElementTarget.switch(WebBrowser.scala:1494)
    at org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser$switch$.to(WebBrowser.scala:3948)
    at org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser$class.enter(WebBrowser.scala:4463)
    at com.iomedico.iostudyoffice.LoginSpec.enter(LoginSpec.scala:18)
    at com.iomedico.iostudyoffice.LoginSpec.login(LoginSpec.scala:100)
...
```

As a workaround If I replaced `enter(username)` with `usernameField.value = username`, etc. The next error comes for `submit()`:

```
WebDriver encountered problem to submit(): POST /session/c423793f-09a0-4a8e-afc0-7a2d6d1f3d6a/element/active did not match a known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
...
    at org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser$class.submit(WebBrowser.scala:3870)
    at com.iomedico.iostudyoffice.LoginSpec.submit(LoginSpec.scala:18)
    at com.iomedico.iostudyoffice.LoginSpec.login(LoginSpec.scala:105)
...
```

In both errors there is this *active did not match a known command*.

How do I get this running?

### followup: bug?

Looking at [the code of AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.0.0-beta-3/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/http/AbstractHttpCommandCodec.java), I think it could be a bug in org.seleniumhq.selenium:**selenium-java**.

```
defineCommand(GET_ACTIVE_ELEMENT, post("/session/:sessionId/element/active"));
```

„post“ seems wrong, doesn’t it?

Comment: I have same bug selenium 3.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a [bug](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2751) now [fixed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/ed15c6c2e592301b523a62ce44dc3ccd5615f37e) in Selenium 3.0 beta 4.